# How to plot Feynman diagrams in Mathematica using FeynCalc and FeynArts?

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I installed [FeynCalc](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation#automatic-installation-) which automatically installs FeynArts:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/master/install.m"]
InstallFeynCalc[]
```

Now I am trying the following [example](https://indico.mpp.mpg.de/event/3707/session/16/contribution/35/material/slides/0.pdf):

```
<< FeynCalc`
topVertex = 
  CreateTopologies[1, 1 -> 2, 
   ExcludeTopologies -> {Tadpoles, WFCorrections}];
diagsVertex = 
  InsertFields[topVertex, {F[2, {1}]} -> {V[1], F[2, {1}]}, 
   InsertionLevel -> {Classes}, Model -> "SM", 
   ExcludeParticles -> {S[1], S[2], S[3], V[3], V[2]}];
Paint[diagsVertex, ColumnsXRows -> {2, 1}]
```

For which I get nothing but this output on my screen:

```
FeynCalc is already loaded! To reload it, please restart the kernel.
$Aborted
Paint(InsertFields(CreateTopologies(1,1->2,ExcludeTopologies->{Tadpoles,WFCorrections}),{F(2,{1})}->{V(1),F(2,{1})},InsertionLevel->{Classes},Model->SM,ExcludeParticles->{S(1),S(2),S(3),V(3),V(2)}),ColumnsXRows->{2,1})
```

Comment: Perhaps you can directly ask the authors of FeynCalc on their forum here: https://feyncalc.github.io/forum .  I'm sure you'll get helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$LoadFeynArts = True; 
Needs["FeynCalc`"];

topVertex = 
  CreateTopologies[1, 1 -> 2, 
   ExcludeTopologies -> {Tadpoles, WFCorrections}];
diagsVertex = 
  InsertFields[topVertex, {F[2, {1}]} -> {V[1], F[2, {1}]}, 
   InsertionLevel -> {Classes}, Model -> "SM", 
   ExcludeParticles -> {S[1], S[2], S[3], V[3], V[2]}];
Paint[diagsVertex, ColumnsXRows -> {2, 1}]
```

Comment: `Paint` seems to not be a function of FC or FA anymore.